# How do you use Selenium to test if your URL is what is expected?

Tags: selenium, web-testing

I'm currently learning Selenium 1.8.0, and I'd like to test whether the current URL is what I want.

I know there's a storeLocation function, but I'm not sure what else I need to do.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

selenium.getLocation() will give you the current URL in the address bar. Since you said you are learning - It would be better you learn Selenium 2 rather than selenium 1.x versions. Reasons are mentioned here

[Obvious reason to move from Selenium RC to Webdriver.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779571/obvious-reason-to-move-from-selenium-rc-to-webdriver/10780224#10780224)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. good points.  But if I learn 1.8 well , will I be able to port that knowledge to selenium 2?

Comment: @Adel not really, thankfully. Did you learn how to drive a carriage before you got your driving license?

Comment: @Frank - Sir, yes I did. And a Rottweiler prior

Comment: @Adel I didn't- what a pitty. But I think you've got it