# how to pass data from a two dimentional parameter array to type() function in selenium rc using junit

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-rc

I'm trying to pass username and passwords in different combinations (valid-valid, valid-invalid, invalid-valid, invalid-invalid) and have them assigned to String variables userName and password and have used a parameterized class.

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FunctionalTestCaseActiTimeParameterization {

    Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox","http://localhost/login.do");

    String userName;
    String password;

    public FunctionalTestCaseActiTimeParameterization(String userName, String password){
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Object[][] getData(){
        return new Object[][]{
            {"admin","manager"},
            {"admin","test"},
            {"test","manager"},
            {"test","test"}
        };
    }

    @Before
    public void openApplication(){
        selenium.start();// start interaction with proxy server
        selenium.open("/");// to open application
        selenium.windowMaximize();// to maximize the window
        selenium.windowFocus();// to focus on current window
    }

    @After
    public void closeApplicaton() throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        selenium.close();// close window
        selenium.stop();// stop interaction with server
    }

    @Test
    public void mainTestMethodLoginLogout() throws InterruptedException{
        selenium.type("//input[@id='username']", userName);
        selenium.type("//input[@type='password']", password);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

and i didn't get any errors or warnings (I've used parameterized but not inside a function so getting a little confused about how to use it inside the type function, 
when run the code gives failure (no error).

I'd be glad if some one can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but why are you doing new work using Selenium RC? It's been deprecated for years: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10779571/954442

Comment: i know. i'm trying to learn webdriver but learning the whole selenium from scratch including rc so that when selenium 3 comes i can learn it easily

Comment: AFAIK, the RC api is just going in the trash, so I'd really concentrate on WebDriver only.

Comment: so is it completely useless to learn how to pass values from a parameterized  to inside a function ?

Comment: No, it's a good question in a way, just try to switch to the WD API. Doesn't affect the answer I've given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself. The code i posted was actually correct but it was not accepting the parameter because i was calling parameters before the page loaded completely.
adding a `Thread.sleep(2000);` resolved the problem.
Thank you for whomever tried..

Answer (score 0):

I think the two-dimensional array approach is a mistake, because looking a little further you need to associate your {username:password} combinations with expected outputs.

Perhaps the expectation only needs to be a boolean ("OK" vs "Not OK"), in which case you could use a `List<MyTestSpec>` where `MyTestSpec` comprises {username, password, wasOK} - but you probably have additional needs, e.g. checking successful login redirects to profile page for different user-levels, checking different types of login failure.

You should really start out by having a separate, distinct `@Test` for each scenario and make each one as comprehensive and detailed as it should be.

Worry about refactoring your Selenium API logic (creating helper functions etc.) only once you have made your failing tests pass and you have locked-down your expectations.

**Note** that the same applies whether using Selenium's RC or WebDriver API.

Comment: i have already done the program as you have described (4 test cases, boolean o/p and printing the warning if got any or succesful page redirect) but this was given as a challenge to our creativity and were also asked to get it by any means necessary (googling, asking in forums, stealing from people who have already done it etc., (i know the last one is ridiculous) ) and were told this was not a programming ability test rather a different one and we will get to know why we were asked to do it only after we do it !!

Comment: i tried the "let me do it on my own" but have gotten stuck!

Comment: oh! and we are not allowed to even think about collections forget using them